# Nginx, awstats and request time

Tags: nginx, awstats

How can I tune nginx to write request time to logs such that awstats can show time taken for each request?

Also, how can I see requests by time taken in awstats?

This is the current format

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Vladimir mentioned, to logs request time, edit your `log_format` directive as belows:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
                      ' $request_time';
```

and set the corresponding variables for `LogFormat` in `awstats` configuration file:

```
LogFormat="%host %other %host_r %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot %other %extra1"
```

Here is an `extra1` section example:

```
ExtraSectionName1="Time to serve requests (seconds)"
ExtraSectionCodeFilter1=""
ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle1="Number of seconds to serve the request"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="extra1,(.*)"
ExtraSectionStatTypes1="H"
```

Building report:

```
awstats.pl -config=model -output -staticlinks > awstats.localhost.html
```

[image]

Comment: Can I drill down to the page level and see the page causing delays?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *$request_time* variable, as specified [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format), e.g.:

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

**Edit:** Oops, missed your second question. You can make *AWStats* parse the new format by using the [LogFormat](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#LogFormat) directive with an *extraN* variable and later use an *ExtraSection* to display the results.